# How to find maximum column width of table second column?

Tags: tables

I want to have an adjustable textual second-column of the table. 
Code where the second column has been manually fitted for the table, since I cannot find a way for the automatic adjustment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l p{.7\linewidth}}
$S$                             & Bland-Altman plane, Tukey Mean-Difference Plot plane \\
$\mathscr{S}'(\mathbf R^n \times \mathbf R^n)$ & Contohunatoehuaoenthanoeuthanoetuheon hnh  tahoeu nahoeu nhon hnhinuous dual of the Schwartz space \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Output

[image]

Outputs with failed manual adjustments

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)
Overfull \hbox (66.03557pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--11
[][] 
[1{/home/masi/.texlive2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.table.aux) )
```

Fig. 2 Piet van Oostrum's answer output

[image]

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly clear what you mean, but if I guess that you want the table to fill the whole width of the page. If not, please explain what you want. If that is what you want you can use `tabularx` instead of `tabular` (with the `tabularx` package) and use the `X` column instead of the `p`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent [ \hrulefill text \hrulefill ]\\

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
$S$                             & Bland-Altman plane, Tukey Mean-Difference Plot plane \\
$\mathscr{S}'(\mathbf R^n \times \mathbf R^n)$ & Contohunato ehuaoenthanoeuthanoetuheon hnh  tahoeu nahoeu nhon hnhinuous dual of the Schwartz space \\
\end{tabularx}

\noindent [ \hrulefill text \hrulefill ]\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. The output is also better, see the body. - - What is the role of `\noindent [ \hrulefill text \hrulefill ]\\``?

Comment: @Masi That's just to show the text width.